# I use Pi for 3D printer server with repetier-server, but can't connect more than 14 printers

Tags: pi-2, usb

14 printers connected 2-usb hub to raspberry pi-2. I want 18 printers to connect one pi. But 15th printer can't install in [repetier-server](https://www.repetier-server.com/) printer setting. How can more than 14 printers connect to pi?

Comment: Please list what you did, the brand of the printers etc. If you got 18 printers, did you try another printer to be the 15th?

Comment: I think you're bumping up against a hard limit - there's some discussion [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=173343) and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=13917) on the raspberrypi.org forums which strongly implies that there's a Pi driver limitation restricting you to a maximum of 14 devices. Even if the driver allowed it I'm not at all sure that the Pi's USB controller has the capacity to deal with that many devices simultaneously. Bear in mind it was designed for use in low-to-mid range mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

There are two limits you may be hitting:

- The USB limit of a max of 5 hubs in a chain. This includes the hub on the RPi itself (that's how it provides 4 ports), and any daisy-chained internal hubs (e.g. a 7-port hub is actually a 4-port hub plugged into another 4-port hub. USB hubs cannot have more than 4 ports). To avoid this, you should try plugging your hubs into the RPi directly, rather than daisy-chaining them
- The number of periodic channels available. This is diagnosed by a `dmesg` message

> INFO:: schedule_periodic: No host channel available for periodic transfer.

AFAIK there is a [patch](http://git.denx.de/?p=linux-denx.git;a=commit;h=9796e39e7a513d8a4acde759ec5d0023645143d8) fixing this, but I haven't tried it myself.

Considering the cost of 3D-printers, buying a second RPi to control them doesn't seem like a huge waste of money, so that's what I would do.